# using File().byLine() with fold()

Tags: d

I am trying to use the fold operation on a range returned by `byLine()`.  I want the lambda which is passed to fold to be a multi-line function.  I have searched google and read the documentation, but cannot find a description as to what the signature of the function should be.  I surmize that one of the pair is the accumulated sum and one is the current element.  This is what I have but it will not build

```
    auto sum = File( fileName, "r" )
        .byLine
        .fold!( (a, b) 
        {
            auto len = b.length;
            return a + len;
        });
```

The error I get back from dmd is:

```
main.d(22): Error: no property `fold` for `(File(null, null)).this(fileName, "r").byLine(Flag.no, '\n')` of type `std.stdio.File.ByLineImpl!(char, char)`
```

So my question is two fold:

1. Is my use of fold in this case valid?
2. How do I pass a curley brace lambda to fold?

I have tried searching google and reading the dlang documentation for fold.  All documentation uses the shortcut lambda syntax `(a, b) => a + b`.

Answer (score 4):

So the way `fold` works is that it accepts a list of function aliases on how to fold the next element in. *if you don't provide it with a starting value*, it uses the first element as the starting value. Quoting the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The call `fold!(fun)(range, seed)` first assigns seed to an internal
> variable `result`, also called the accumulator. Then, for each element
> x in range,  `result = fun(result, x)` gets evaluated. Finally, `result`
> is returned. The  one-argument version `fold!(fun)(range)` works
> similarly, but **it uses the  first element of the range as the seed**
> (the range must be non-empty).

The reason why your original code didn't work is because you can't add an integer to a string (the seed was the first line of the file).

The reason why your latest version works (although only on 32-bit machines, since you can't reassign a size_t to an int on 64-bit machines) is because you gave it a starting value of `0` to seed the fold. So that is the correct mechanism to use for your use case.

The documentation is a bit odd, because the function is actually not an eponymous template, so it has *two* parts to the documentation -- one for the template, and one for the fold function. The fold function doc lists the runtime parameters that are accepted by `fold`, in this case, the input range and the seed. The documentation link for it is here: https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#.fold.fold

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  I am relatively new to D and find the documentation lacking regarding templates and function literals.  This cleared things up for me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to tweak the answer provied by Akshay.  The following compiled and ran:

```
module example;

import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm.iteration : fold;

void main() {
    string fileName = "test1.txt";
    auto sum = File(fileName, "r")
        .byLine
        .fold!( (a, b) {
            // You can define the lambda function using the `{}` syntax
            auto len = b.length;
            return a + len;
        })(0); // Initialize the fold with a value of 0
}
```